# Scala unFlatMap

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

I would like to perform something like unFlatMap. Lets say that I have stream:

`Stream("|","A","d","a","m","|","J","o","h","n", ...)`

Stream could be infinite. I would like to convert it to:

`Stream("Adam", "John", ...)`

Ofcourse it is only example. In general I would like to perform some operation on elements separated by delimiter, Generic signature would be:

`def unFlatMap[B](isSeparator:A => Boolean)(group:Seq[A] => B):TraversableOnce[B]`

How to do that in clean and memory efficient way?

Comment: If the stream is how your example has it, don't really need `isSeparator`. `head` is your separator (say `h`). Assemble the item with `.takeWhile(h!=)`. Repeat (as an iterator)

Comment: You could take a look at how the `GroupWithIterator` is implemented in [KollFlitz](https://github.com/Sciss/KollFlitz). Your operation would be `x.groupWith((a, b) => b != "|").map(_.mkString.stripMargin).toStream`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def groupStream[A, B](s: Stream[A])(isSeparator: A => Boolean)(group: Seq[A] => B): Stream[B] = 
  group(s.takeWhile(!isSeparator(_)).toList) #:: groupStream(s.dropWhile(!isSeparator(_)).drop(1))(isSeparator)(group)
```

Or if you want an easier to read but more verbose version:

```
def groupStream[A, B](s: Stream[A])(isSeparator: A => Boolean)(group: Seq[A] => B): Stream[B] = {
  def isNotSeparator(i: A): Boolean = ! isSeparator(i)

  def doGroupStream(s: Stream[A]): Stream[B] = 
    group(s.takeWhile(isNotSeparator).toList) #:: doGroupStream(s.dropWhile(isNotSeparator).drop(1))

  doGroupStream(s)
}
```

If you want a implicit method on Stream, you could also do

```
implicit class ImprovedStream[A](val s: Stream[A]) extends AnyVal {
    def groupStream[B](isSeparator: A => Boolean)(group: Seq[A] => B): Stream[B] = {
      def isNotSeparator(i: A): Boolean = ! isSeparator(i)

      def doGroupStream(st: Stream[A]): Stream[B] = 
        group(st.takeWhile(isNotSeparator).toList) #:: doGroupStream(st.dropWhile(isNotSeparator).drop(1))

      doGroupStream(s)
    }
}
```

Now, using your example:

```
val a = Stream("|" ,"A","d","a","m","|","J","o","h","n", "|", "M", "a", "r", "y", "|", "J", "o", "e")

val c = groupStream(a)(_ == "|")(_.mkString)

c.take(10).toList
//  List[String] = List("", Adam, John, Mary, Joe, "", "", "", "", "")
```

Using the implicit version:

```
val c = groupStream(a)(_ == "|")(_.mkString)
```